# How to print a quote based on the inputed Zodiac Sign with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I'm making a console personality test and I want to print a quote for the inputed zodiac sign of the player. I don't want to use tons of `if` statements, can I do this with dictionaries and loops?

Where the keys are the zodiac signs and the values are the specific quotes, then using a loop and a short if statement to loop the keys with the given input and print the corresponding value which is the quote.

Here's my code:

```py
sign = input("What is your zodiac sign ? (Enter one of these: aries, taurus, gemini, cancer, leo, virgo, libra, scorpio, sagittarius, capricorn, aquarius, pisces )  ---> ")


zodiac_signs = {
  "aries": "quote", 
  "taurus": "quote", 
  "gemini": "quote", 
  "cancer": "quote", 
  "leo": "quote", 
  "virgo": "quote", 
  "libra": "quote", 
  "scorpio": "quote", 
  "sagittarius": "quote", 
  "capricorn": "quote", 
  "aquarius": "quote", 
  "pisces": "quote"
  }
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding up to what Challe said, you might also want to lowercase the input so that the keys match even if they use Uppercase for the first letter.

Comment: can python do that for me ? I just warned the player to enter only lowercase..

Comment: Yes. You can do it with .lower() You put it at the end of the input line or make a different variable, like lowered_sign = sign.lower()

Answer (score 2):

You could just get the zodiac sign from the dictionary with

```
sign = input("What is your zodiac sign ? (Enter one of these: aries, taurus, gemini, cancer, leo, virgo, libra, scorpio, sagittarius, capricorn, aquarius, pisces ) ---> ")

zodiac_signs = { "aries": "quote", "taurus": "quote", "gemini": "quote", "cancer": "quote", "leo": "quote", "virgo": "quote", "libra": "quote", "scorpio": "quote", "sagittarius": "quote", "capricorn": "quote", "aquarius": "quote", "pisces": "quote" }

try:
    print(zodiac_signs[sign])
except(Exception e):
    print("That's not a zodiac sign")
```

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries have a `get` method specifically for this problem.

```
print(zodiac_signs.get(sign, "That's not a zodiac sign"))
```

It functions by returning the value of the given key if it's in the `dict`, otherwise it returns the given default argument.